# Simplify Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, html

I have two functions that check for the correct answer:

If btnA clicked --> check if correct and continue quiz
if btnB clicked --> check if correct and continue quiz

How can I simplify these two functions and make 1 function that checks answer depending on which button was clicked.

```
 function cleanCheckAnswer() {
  if(cleanBtn.value === questions[pos][3]) {
    console.log('correct');
    correct++;
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
  } else {
    console.log ('incorrect');
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
  }
}

function uncleanCheckAnswer() {
  if(uncleanBtn.value === questions[pos][3]) {
    console.log('correct');
    correct++;
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
  } else {
    console.log('incorrect');
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. JS code alone without reference is hard to understand. Also note, that SO is not a [Code Review Service](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: General advice: Almost any time you're doing the same thing inside both the `if` and the `else` blocks you can just do it once after both. That cuts at least 4 lines right off the bat. In fact, it eliminates both `else` blocks.

Comment: Why not just combine both using `||` since the code you are running is the same in clean and unclean cases?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function genericCheckAnswer(value) {
  if(value === questions[pos][3]) {
    console.log('correct');
    correct++;
  } else {
    console.log('incorrect');
  }
  pos++;
  renderQuestion();
}


function cleanCheckAnswer() {
  genericCheckAnswer(cleanBtn.value)
}
  
function uncleanCheckAnswer() {
  genericCheckAnswer(uncleanBtn.value)
}
```